# Least squares minimization for multiple variables matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares, minimization

I need to find the value of tree variables: `a`, `b` and `c`, by finding a global minimum for least squares method. My function is as follows:

```
f = (1/a)*(asinh((Z(i)/b)^(1/c))^(-1)
```

where `i` is the index of vector `Z`. The vector `Z` has 9 values given in the task.
I also have a vector with 9 values for `s`. 
The least squares method need to sum differences between values computed by function `f` with the values from vector `s`. It should look something like this:

```
((s(i)-f(i))/s(i))^2
```

I also have the boundaries for value `a`, `b` and `c`:

`10e10>a>10e19`, `10e-7>b>50`, `10e-15>c>10`.

I tried to use the `lsqnonlin` but I have no idea how to do it. I will appreciate any of your help!

I tried to do something like this:

```
function f=Fsigma(x, Z, sigma)
f=0;
for i=1:length(sigma)
    f=f+((sigma(i)-((1/x(1,:))*(asinh((Z(i)/x(2,:))^(1/x(3,:)))^(-1))))/sigma(i))^2
end
end
```

and call this function in `lsqnonlin` like this:

```
Z= [1.49E+18 1.49E+19 1.49E+20 1.99E+15 1.99E+16 1.99E+17 1.49E+13 1.49E+14 1.49E+15];
sigma = [55.1705 79.1016 105.636 25.4809 40.8572 61.7238 12.8147 21.4054 34.8319];

a=linspace(10e10,10e19);
b=linspace(10e-7,50);
c=linspace(10e-15,10);
x=[a; b; c];
p=lsqnonlin(Fsigma(x,Z,sigma));
```

Comment: please post the code that you have so far, so your question gets a bit clearer

Comment: @max I just posted my code. I tried to change the example that I found in documentation, so I will be able to find all tree variables: a, b ad c instead of finding just one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK @Agata, I'll go through it in detail, so you can learn some basics.

First, how to hand functions to functions: *function handles* aka. the `@`-operator

```
fnc = @(x) Fsigma(x,Z,sigma);
```

`fnc` is an object -- in fact, it is a something that points at the function `Fsigma`. However, it even overshadows the additional inputs of `Fsigma` by declaring that its only input is `x` (this is called an *anonymous function handle*, indicated by the `()`, in between which you define the inputs that someone calling `fnc` may use. The other inputs to `Fsigma` in this line are the values of the variables that they have *in this line*.

**boundaries**
Boundaries should be provided as vectors:

```
% bounds
lb = [  10e10;
        10e-7;
        10e-15];
ub = [  10e19;
        50;
        10];
```

**initial guess + optimization call** if you read [the docs of `lsqnonlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html), it requires an initial guess

```
% initial guess
x0 = ones(3,1);
% optimization call: x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,lb,ub)
[p,fval] = lsqnonlin(fnc,x0,lb,ub)
```

**Note to the cost function**
`lsqnonlin` is better if you do not provide a summed cost but an array of errors (see the docs, again). So I adjust you `Fsigma`-function

```
function f = Fsigma(x, Z, sigma)
f = ((sigma-((1/x(1))./ asinh((Z./x(2)).^(1/x(3)))) )./sigma).^2;
end
```

If you want to have use a single output -- as most optimization algorithms require from their cost function -- you can use [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

Have a look at the **full code**

```
Z = [1.49E+18 1.49E+19 1.49E+20 1.99E+15 1.99E+16 1.99E+17 1.49E+13 1.49E+14 1.49E+15];
sigma = [55.1705 79.1016 105.636 25.4809 40.8572 61.7238 12.8147 21.4054 34.8319];

% bounds
lb = [  10e10;
        10e-7;
        10e-15];
ub = [  10e19;
        50;
        10];
% initial guess
x0 = ones(3,1);

% create an anyonymous function handle (using @(x)
fnc = @(x) Fsigma(x,Z,sigma);
% optimization call: x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,lb,ub)
[p,fval] = lsqnonlin(fnc,x0,lb,ub);

% optimization call: x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
fnc2 = @(x) sqrt(sum(fnc(x).^2));
[p2,fval2] = fmincon(fnc2,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);


% cost function
function f = Fsigma(x, Z, sigma)
f = ((sigma-((1/x(1))./ asinh((Z./x(2)).^(1/x(3)))) )./sigma).^2;
end
```

PS: note that this community is not a coding service, so do your readings the next time!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately i'm totally new to matlab, so the task was way to hard for me... I have one more question, I do not know why the least squares (for the function f called with the variables a, b, c (from result) comparing to values of sigma) is equal to 1, while it should be as close to 0 as possible...

Comment: I assume that you are talking about the function `Fsigma`. The problem is ill-posed. In fact, both algorithms stop at the initial guess (and tell you this, that they don't find a decreasing direction). You may get it working with scaling the  parameter as they have a very strange range (the first index -- what you call *a* is in [10e10,10e19], while the other parameter are in (0,50]